# Dependent mapper not appears in implementation and expression does not see it

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have two mappers, A and B. A uses B but source is for both the same. I want to be able to call mapper B from inside mapper A but I don't know how. Example:

```
class A {
  B fieldB;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface BMapper {
    //mapping rules here
    B mapToDomain(CommonEntity entity);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = BMapper.class)
public interface AMapper {
    //mapping rules here
    //HERE I WANT TO INVOKE MAPPER B and for B to map to specific A.B target
    A mapToDomain(CommonEntity entity);
}
```

I tried with expression but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mappers in `Mapper#uses` are only injected in the implementation if they are explicitly used by MapStruct, otherwise they are ignored.

What ou can do is to tell MapStruct that you want to map the source parameter to `fieldB`

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = BMapper.class)
public interface AMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "fieldB", source = "entity"
    A mapToDomain(CommonEntity entity);
}
```